# Python background process that reverts wallpaper when the user changes it

Tags: python, events, background-process

I want to make a python program that runs in the background which changes the wallpaper back to a default wallpaper whenever user changes the wallpaper. 
I have successfully changed the current wallpaper using the code: -

```py
    import ctypes

    path = r"C:\Users\..."    #Actual path to the image
    res = ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, path, 0)
```

I also have successfully converted it to executable without console using pyinstaller.

Now I would like it to run so that it 'listens' for events such as wallpaper change by user and then runs this code to revert back the change. I assume this can be done using ctype library in python, but I do not have much knowledge of using it. I am not even sure that this can be done in python, or should I even use events? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple young man;

Just do

```
> import ctypes     
       while 3>2:
>      path = r"C:\Users\..."    #Actual path to the image
>      res = ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, path, 0)
```

And BTW try to run it with;
[image]

And If you are determined to run a .exe which i don't recommend because of the window that it opens and can be easily closed you can ofcourse;

You may create a scheduled task using the following steps (the task will run when the PC gets locked):

```
Open Task Scheduler
Click on Create task... under Action (menu bar)
Name the task on the General tab
Add a new trigger on the tab Triggers
    Begin the task: On workstation lock (drop-down menu on top of the New Trigger window)
Finally, add a new action on the Actions tab (you just have to browse for the program)
```

Because of this I don't recommend it on the other side with the python option in the picture above if you use that you don't need to do that and the user wont even notice that a task is being executed behind. 
It's more sneaky and effective way. I am an Ethical Hacker and I have done what you are trying to do and well Good Luck above was some Advice.

And of course you would want to run the program when the computer starts for that just add this to your whole program as;

```
    import getpass
    import os
    USER_NAME = getpass.getuser()


    def add_to_startup(file_path=""):
        if file_path == "":
            file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        bat_path = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' % USER_NAME
        with open(bat_path + '\\' + "open.bat", "w+") as bat_file:
            bat_file.write(r'start "" %s' % file_path)
    add_to_startup(__file__)

    import ctypes
    while 3>2:
        path = r"C:\Users\..."    #Actual path to the image
        res = ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, path, 0)
```

Comment: Just tried this code and the pc crashes, I added 
`import time` 
and did 
`time.sleep(3)`
in the while loop and works fine...

But are you sure that infinite loop is the best approach? Can't we do it through events?